# setOnLongClickListener not working

Tags: android, onlongclicklistener

I am using a third party library. It makes images be draggable, and scale when you pinch, and rotate. I am trying to implement deletion of the image, and have made a method that does delete the image you place your finger on. Now I just need to call it. The only place I have successfully called it from is onDraw. Ideally I would call it on a doubleTap, because the user will longClick it to drag it. But longClick is apparently easier so i was testing that first. Here is my code. Scroll to the bottom to see my setOnClickListener. I will show you the class code before the setOnClickListener to give you some context:

```
public class PhotoSortrView extends View implements MultiTouchObjectCanvas<PhotoSortrView.Img> {

        private ArrayList<Integer> mDrawables = new ArrayList<Integer>();// { R.drawable.m74hubble, R.drawable.catarina, R.drawable.tahiti, R.drawable.sunset, R.drawable.lake };

        public void addDrawable(int drawable, Context context){
            Resources res = context.getResources();
            mDrawables.add(drawable);

            mImages.add(new Img(drawable, res));
            invalidate();
        }

        private ArrayList<Img> mImages = new ArrayList<Img>();
        private AppUser user;

        // --

        private MultiTouchController<Img> multiTouchController = new MultiTouchController<Img>(this);

        // --

        private PointInfo currTouchPoint = new PointInfo();

        private boolean mShowDebugInfo = true;

        private static final int UI_MODE_ROTATE = 1, UI_MODE_ANISOTROPIC_SCALE = 2;

        private int mUIMode = UI_MODE_ROTATE;

        // --

        private Paint mLinePaintTouchPointCircle = new Paint();

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        public PhotoSortrView(Context context) {
            this(context, null);
        }

        public PhotoSortrView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            this(context, attrs, 0);
        }

        public PhotoSortrView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            init(context);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        private void init(Context context) {
            Resources res = context.getResources();
            for (int i = 0; i < mDrawables.size(); i++)
                mImages.add(new Img(mDrawables.get(i), res));

            mLinePaintTouchPointCircle.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            mLinePaintTouchPointCircle.setStrokeWidth(5);
            mLinePaintTouchPointCircle.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
            mLinePaintTouchPointCircle.setAntiAlias(true);
            this.setLongClickable(true);

            this.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Long Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("long clicking", "long clicking");
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
```

I'm new to Android so maybe do not fully understand the context of this library class. I call this class in my activity like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dressing_room);
    photoSorter = new PhotoSortrView(this);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            this.addContentView(photoSorter, params);
```

Its a view that gets added to this activity, but it has a canvas and can add lots of the draggable images. Thanks.

**EDIT** I changed it to

```
this.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

               // @Override
                //public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                //  Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Long Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //  Log.d("long clicking", "long clicking");
                //    return true;
               // }

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Long Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("long clicking", "long clicking");
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
```

And that works. Can we get from that to a doubleTap?

Comment: try mLinePaintTouchPointCircle.setOnLongClickListener....

Comment: @RanjitPati I got an error as it is not applicable for type Paint. Thanks though.

Comment: did you import `android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;`?

Comment: as i don't have any good idea in graphics things but still  i think there is some problem in your context.

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan I did just then and it has a warning that it is never used. Thanks.

Comment: @RanjitPati I added more information about this class to my question just now. Thanks

Comment: ok do one  thing .create Context variable in your PhotoSortrView class like private Context context; and assign it to activity context inside the constructure. and use it with onclicklistener.

Comment: @RanjitPati setOnLongClickListener is undefined for the type Context. It asks me to cast from type Context to type View unfortunately, which also doesn't work.

Comment: @RanjitPati I have updated my question down the bottom :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a built-in [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) that is able to "catch" all common interactions between the device and the user, including double tap. However to set it up for a single View, or a selection of Views, you have to do a bit of grunt work. I'll post the code of my test activity now:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private GestureDetector gd;
    View.OnTouchListener otl;

    class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gd = new GestureDetector(this, new MyGestureDetector());
        otl = new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return gd.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        };
        LinearLayout cotainerView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        TextView tvNormal = new TextView(this);
        tvNormal.setText("Normal text view");
        tvNormal.setHeight(50);
        DoubleTapTextView tvDoubleTap = new DoubleTapTextView(this);
        tvDoubleTap.setText("Double tap text view");
        tvDoubleTap.setHeight(50);
        tvDoubleTap.setOnClickListener(this);
        tvDoubleTap.setOnTouchListener(otl);
        containerView.addView(tvNormal);
        containerView.addView(tvDoubleTap);
    }

    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

So the trick is to pass the onTouch event, as well as its argument (`MotionEvent e`) to your custom GestureListener. This way, every Gesture (Touch event) will be listened for, but your custom listener will execute `onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e)` method only in the case the gesture is double tap. Hopefully, you understand the idea behind this, and as a treat, I'm posting a screenshot of the app running in an emulator to show you that the event is actually caught :)
[image: Screenshot]

**EDIT: Here are the key points of the solution**

1. `Activity implements OnClickListener`
2. Register the desired View for both `OnClickLister` and `OnTouchListener`

   ```
   tvDoubleTap.setOnClickListener(this); //Your activity implements OnClickListener
   tvDoubleTap.setOnTouchListener(otl); //The wrapper listener from which you call your custom one
   ```
3. Inside the basic OnTouchListener, pass the argument to your custom GestureListener

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       return gd.onTouchEvent(event);
   }
   ```
4. Inside your custom GestureListener's `onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e)` method, implement your solution.

   ```
   class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
       @Override
       public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           return true;
       }
   }
   ```

Credits: Thanks to **[gav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111734/gav)**, for his research on [his question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection)

Comment: On second thought, this is a pretty bad solution, I'll edit the answer once I come up with a good one.

Comment: Were you meaning that I add that to my class that implements double-tap, or make that as a whole new class? I wouldn't know how to implement this one. I will leave it for now anyway, you or someone else may have something better later on. Thanks.

Comment: I will edit it later (in about one-two hours) with full solution

Comment: Sorry this took so long. My Internet connection was failing and so did I :) Anyway, I'm about to edit the answer with a pretty strange, but working solution.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am about to try this out. Do you know why it is quite a bit of code to get it working? No one else answered so it was not just an obvious small block of code. Is it always like that in Android or is my setup just awkward for this event listener?

Comment: It works! Thanks! Very detailed and easy to understand answer emphasizing the key points.